# How to test JPA entity insertion is done?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactional

1. The question is about how to test whether persist entity works or not. I think it makes sense to test whether JPA entity mapping is correct and everything works as expected, especially for complex entity mapping with @OneToMany/@ElementCollection/@ManyToMany/@OneToOne with *cascade* attributes (CascadeType.ALL, for example). And be sure that all FK/PK/Unique constraints are satisfied.
2. This is the general question. The concrete part is about Spring Testing Framework. You can see on the code below, where DAO layer is testing, but because test method is marked as *@Transactional*, changes *should* be rollbacked, here is *should* instead of *must*, because how I can be sure, the changes were actually saved in the database at all, probably everything is hold in the memory, because transaction was marked for rollback, so no data is really sent to the database?
3. More important, that this test is failed, because account.getId() returns 0 (id generation is done using @SequenceGenerator), but it seems that this value is never assigned into the Account's id field. This test is only passed when the method is annotated with @Rollback(false), so of course no rollback occurs.
4. Am I right, that in this case when @Transactional for testing is used, everything is in the memory (at least, until flush() is not called), so it is not possible to check database constraints working.
5. And according to the thoughts above, what is the appropriate way to test entity insertion, and be sure that inserting was done, and then rollback everything to the initial state, so to run other tests? (clean up the database inside @Before every time test is executed?)
6. I don't want to use DBUnit, using Spring there is no sense at all to use DBUnit.

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration(
   locations = {...})
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   public abstract class JpaRepositoryTest {
   }

   public class JpaAccountRepositoryTest extends JpaRepositoryTest {
       @Inject
       private AccountRepository accountRepository;

       @Inject
       private Account account;    

       @Test
       @Transactional
       public void createAccount() {
           accountRepository.save(account);

           assertEquals(1, account.getId()); // this assertion will be failed, until @Rollback(false) is used
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The separate testing database is used (no fake in-memory database, but the same database platform which is used for production), so it is safe to delete everything on it, actually I create the database from scratch (using spring jdbc:initialize-database) before running tests.

Answer (score 2):

If your constraints are not deferred, and you flush the session after the call to save, everything will be written into database, and constraints will be applied. You may then execute queries and check if your entities are returned. The returned entities will be the ones held in memory by the session, though.

When I really want to check that something is persisted correctly, I generally execute the persist in one transaction (using a TransactionTemplate), and then execute queries to verify everything is OK after the transaction commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a combined em.flush() and then em.clear().
em.flush has been described above. em.clear() will detach all entities currently known by the context.

After this you can try to find your recently persisted entities and it will be as if you would add them to your context, that is, doing a real find against your entities. I have an example of that from a question I posted here on SO.

[How can I reliably unit test updates of a JPA entity in a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160398/how-can-i-reliably-unit-test-updates-of-a-jpa-entity-in-a-unit-test)