# How can I reliably unit test updates of a JPA entity in a unit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, jpa

I have this test setup where I'm using spring, derby and JPA and I want to test whether updates work.

I can't really do this in the standard way, that is. Create an entity object, persist, find object again, change some field in the object, persist again, do a find to see whether it has changed.

The problem with that approach is that I don't get a new instance of the entity. It is always the same. So I can't really tell if update works correctly because I am always changing the same object, so any change is reflected prematurely.

If I make a change to some object without merging it with the persistencecontext, and then try to do a find on that object, the change is already present in the find as it is always working with the same object.

Is there any way I can lose the context and do a real test that updating is working correctly?

Here is my current code:

```
@Test
public void canUpdate() {

    JsonTestEntity entity1 = new JsonTestEntity();
    JsonTestEntity entity2 = new JsonTestEntity();

    String message = "OmegaCV1";
    String message2 = "OmegaCV2";

    entity1.setMessage(message);
    entity2.setMessage(message2);

    em.persist(entity1);
    em.persist(entity2);

    em.flush();

    JsonTestEntity jsonTestEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());

    assertNotNull("Could not find persisted entity", jsonTestEntity);
    assertEquals("Was not same entity", message2, jsonTestEntity.getMessage());

    String changeMessage = "Changed message";
    jsonTestEntity.setMessage(changeMessage);

    JsonTestEntity unChangedEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());

    assertEquals("Message was prematurely changed", message2, unChangedEntity.getMessage());
    em.merge(jsonTestEntity);

    JsonTestEntity changedEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());
    assertEquals("Message was not changed", changeMessage, changedEntity.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there was a possibility to disable EntityManager's 1st level cache - it would solve your problem :)

So I have a few ideas :

1. If your EntityManager is per-transaction - just do the `persist()` and `find()` in different transactions.
2. Use `em.clear()` - it will detach all managed entities. Don't forget to `em.flush()` before this to commit the changes.
3. If you use Hibernate - clear the Session after `persist().flush()` it before :

   Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
   session.flush();
   session.clear();
4. Also you can reload the entity's state using `Session.refresh()`

Docs :

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative I have seen used in unit tests is to use a native query which will be guaranteed to straight to the database.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select ... from ....");
List list = query.getResultList(); // or getSingleResult();
```

which will return a List of Object []

Comment: That is true, but it doesn't verify that you can actually save the entity through the entity, which in this case is the means available to persist the object. Your example seems to be more an API verification test for the orm implementation itself IMHO.

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow. You want to test that something is correctly saved to the database, no?  AFAIK, the above will issue a native SQL query directly against the database bypassing any first or second level cache or persistence session associated with the EM just as if you did it via a raw JDBC connection.

Comment: yes.. but it doesn't test the entity class, I could issue your example code without having specified any entity classes, correct? If correct then it's not what I'm after since I want to test that an entity can be saved by actually handing it to the JPA provider.

Comment: FFS, you want to test an entity has been saved. How would you do that? Query the database. What does the above do? Queries the database. Does this code care how your entity got into the database? No. So save your entity using the code you originally provided and then issue a native query to check if its there.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually pretty frustrating to get JPA to "dumb-down" and read the database again.

I think you can get what you want by calling `EntityManager.refresh(entity2);`

You can also add `@Cacheable(false)`to JsonTestEntity class.  Of course this has the big disadvantage that you have to put it back later.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how to fix it:

```
@Test
public void canUpdate() {

    JsonTestEntity entity1 = new JsonTestEntity();
    JsonTestEntity entity2 = new JsonTestEntity();

    String message = "OmegaCV1";
    String message2 = "OmegaCV2";

    entity1.setMessage(message);
    entity2.setMessage(message2);

    em.persist(entity1);
    em.persist(entity2);

    em.clear(); // Clears the entitymanager so jsonTestEntity != entity2

    JsonTestEntity jsonTestEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());

    assertNotNull("Could not find persisted entity", jsonTestEntity);
    assertEquals("Was not same entity", message2, jsonTestEntity.getMessage());

    String changeMessage = "Changed message";
    jsonTestEntity.setMessage(changeMessage);

    em.clear(); // same reason as above, I cannot however use flush here as that would commit the changed message

    JsonTestEntity unChangedEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());

    assertEquals("Message was prematurely changed", message2, unChangedEntity.getMessage());
    em.merge(jsonTestEntity);

    em.flush(); // since merge performs an update in this case, I need to flush to commit the update, after the flush --> unchangedEntity.getMessage().equals(jsonTestEntity.getMessage())
    em.clear(); // I clear again to get separate objects

    JsonTestEntity changedEntity = em.find(JsonTestEntity.class, entity2.getId());
    assertEquals("Message was not changed", changeMessage, changedEntity.getMessage());


}
```